# How to change default linked application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, mdm

We are developing an hybrid mobile application. One of our requirement is to change default application for email and web blinks.

Is it possible to change default browser to some custom browser when I click on a weblink?

Is it possible to change default email client to specific one on mail links?

I am trying with Maas360 MDM but no success.

Any suggestion?

Comment: No,  there is no way you can override the default handlers for mailto and http

Comment: If you like to open a link in chrome try this https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/links